# Android: USB debug not working properly

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I'm having some trouble with the USB debugging for Android via Eclipse:
All my devices are recognized by the DDMS (I can see everyone of them in the logcat) but some of them don't work with the USB debugging.

I can't start my application on the device via Eclipse because it says: "No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.".

Obviously I've got the USB Debug flag checked on the devices...

I'm working with:

- Eclipse Version: 4.2.1  - Build id: M20120914-1800
- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G56)

Nexus S, Galaxy S3 and a bunch of other devices work; Galaxy S2, Galaxy Note and some other won't...

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

**EDIT:**

**Mistery solved**... I'm a total idiot... in my manifest file I have

```
<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="13"
   android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

And those devices I listed above have previous Android versions... it all works great if I set correctly the minSdkVersion value! So sorry for the time loss!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **look for the USB driver for your device**
- **install it**

Then, In Command Prompt, run `adb devices`. Check if your device is listed...

You can find Samsung universal USB drivers [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?5kcxc1yovvl6740)

Comment: In mac os X I don't think there is a way to install usb drivers... they don't even exist, I think...

Comment: Look at the edit in my question... thank you anyway for your answers! Sorry again!

Comment: @CRUSADER I reported your link because it's misleading and the only real download is an exe, which doesn't work on a mac.